# ASP.net restore checkbox state

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, android-checkbox

i have the following cenario:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="tab_indexer" runat="server" Value="tab_id" />
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab_id" />
        <label for="tab_id">Identificação</label>
        <div class="tabcontainer"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab_message" />
        <label for="tab_message">Mensagem</label>
        <div class="tabcontainer"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Without changing the structure of the page (because my ASP.net Application is already working under this built) i need to, when the input[type="radio"] changes the checked attribute, it saves it's id on the "tab_indexer" hiddenField, and, when the page loads, gets the input[type="radio"] by the Id stores in the HiddenField value and set it checked.

What would be the Javascript for that (i already binded the JQuery js package on the page)?

So far, thanks to another question i did on Stackoverflow, i got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function(){$("tab_indexer").attr("value", $(this).attr("id"));});
  $($("tab_indexer").val()).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

But without sucess.

Comment: There are many things like `type=radio` etc. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `tab_indexer` is a ASP.NET control, you have to use [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In jQuery when you want elemnts to be selected using use [**ID Selector (“#id”)**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), i.e. prefix id with `#`

Change your code as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get tab_indexer element
    var tab_indexer = $("#" + <%= tab_indexer.ClientID %> );
    //Set checkbox checked with value stored in tab_indexer
    $('#' + tab_indexer.val()).prop('checked', 'checked');

    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function () {
        $(tab_indexer).val($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Very thanks, i'll see throught it... i beleave that's what i'm looking for... really great Satpal

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `type=radio` and needs to use proper id selector for tab_indexer, i.e `$("#<%=tab_indexer.ClientID")` and a logic to set the value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //bind event click
  $("input[type=radio]").on('click', function()
           {$("#<%=tab_indexer.ClientID").attr("value", $(this).attr("id"));});

  //set selected radio button checked
  var selectedRadioId=$("#<%=tab_indexer.ClientID").val();
  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    if(this.value==selectedRadioId){
      this.checked=true;
    }
  });

});
```